# Ajuda com função para add e remover DIVs com Autoincremento

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

Fiz um código para adicionar uma DIV (wrap-produtos) com todos os elementos HTML que estão dentro desta assim que é pressionado o botão "+". Cada DIV é adicionada uma embaixo da outra com as mesmas características, o que muda é o autoincremento que é feito no "Número" e em seus names e id's. Cada DIV obtém em sua direita um botão "X", onde este botão precisa excluir a DIV a qual o mesmo pertence, ou seja, cada botão exclui o seu index. Como posso fazer essa função, onde ao excluir a DIV de escolha, é feito automaticamente o decremento do index do "Número", por exemplo, se tem o Número 1,2,3,4 e eu excluir o 3, o Número 4 vai para 3, e o proximo add será o 4 novamente.

index.php:

```
<div id="allProducts" name="allProducts">
    <div class="produtos-wrap" id="wrap-produtos-1" name="wrap-produtos-1"> <!---- div que é clonada !---->
        <div class=" text-center select_height">
            <b>Número:</b>
            <div id="index" class="font-pop">1</div>
        </div>

        <div class=" select_height" id="div_produtos">
            <b>Produto:</b>
            <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-show-subtext="false" data-live-search="true" name="select_produtos-1" id="select_produtos-1" onchange="initProdutos(1);">
                <?php
                foreach ($result2 as $item_produtos) {
                    echo '<option data-subtext="' . $item_produtos['desc_produto'] . '" value="'
                    . $item_produtos['desc_produto'] . '">' . $item_produtos['desc_produto'] . '</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="text-center select_height">
            <b>Embalagem:</b>
            <br>
            <input type="text" maxlength="2" class="edit-input font-pop" id="embalagem-1" name="embalagem-1" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="text-center select_height">
            <b>Preço:</b>
            <br>
            <input type="text" maxlength="5" id="preco-1" name="preco-1" class="edit-input font-pop">
        </div>

        <div class="text-center select_height">
            <b>Quantidade:</b>
            <br>
            <input type="text" maxlength="3" class="edit-input font-pop" value="0" id="quantidade-produto-1" name="quantidade-produto-1">
        </div>

        <div class="text-center select_height">
            <b>Preço do Produto:</b>
            <div id="preco-produto-1" name="preco-produto-1" class="font-pop"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="text-center select_height">
            <button id="remove-1" name="remove-1" class="remover-1" onclick="remove()">X</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <hr>
</div>
<button id="add-button" onclick="addProduct()">+</button>
```

elements.php ( de onde é trago o conteudo para adicionar as DIVs ):

```
<?php $id = $_GET['id']; ?>
<div class="produtos-wrap" id="wrap-produtos-<?= $id ?>" name="wrap-produtos-<?= $id ?>">
    <div class=" text-center select_height">
        <b>Número:</b>
        <div id="index" class="font-pop"><?= $id ?></div>
    </div>

    <div class=" select_height" id="div_produtos">
        <b>Produto:</b>
        <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-show-subtext="false" data-live-search="true" name="select_produtos-<?= $id ?>" id="select_produtos-<?= $id ?>" onchange="initProdutos(<?= $id ?>);">
            <?php
            foreach ($result2 as $item_produtos) {
                echo '<option data-subtext="' . $item_produtos['desc_produto'] . '" value="'
                . $item_produtos['desc_produto'] . '">' . $item_produtos['desc_produto'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center select_height">
        <b>Embalagem:</b>
        <br>
        <input type="text" maxlength="2" class="edit-input font-pop" id="embalagem-<?= $id ?>" name="embalagem-<?= $id ?>" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="text-center select_height">
        <b>Preço:</b>
        <br>
        <input type="text" maxlength="5" id="preco-<?= $id ?>" name="preco-<?= $id ?>" class="edit-input font-pop">
    </div>

    <div class="text-center select_height">
        <b>Quantidade:</b>
        <br>
        <input type="text" maxlength="3" class="edit-input font-pop" value="0" id="quantidade-produto-<?= $id ?>" name="quantidade-produto-<?= $id ?>">
    </div>

    <div class="text-center select_height">
        <b>Preço do Produto:</b>
        <div id="preco-produto-<?= $id ?>" name="preco-produto-<?= $id ?>" class="font-pop"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center select_height">
        <button id="remove-<?= $id ?>" name="remove-<?= $id ?>" class="remover-<?= $id ?>">X</button>
    </div>
</div>  
<hr>
```

Function addProduct():

```
var index = 1;

function addProduct() {
    var id = index + 1;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "elements.php?id=" + id,
        //CASO DÊ TUDO CERTO
        success: function(data) {
            var div = document.getElementById('allProducts');
            div.innerHTML += data;
            index = id;
        },
        error: function(request, error) {
            console.log(error);
            // console.log("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
}
```

Function remove():

```
function remove() {
    const remover = $('.remover');
    const div = $('#produtos-wrap-');
    remover.onclick(div.remove());
    index - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas fiz esse exemplo bem básico.

Tem dois modelos, um remove o irmão de cima e a si mesmo, e ou outro é um filho que remove o pai e a si mesmo. Então se o seu botão vem depois do elemento vc usa o `prev()`, mas se o botão está dentro de um pai vc usa o `parent()`

```js
$('.brow').on('click', function () {
 $(this).prev('div').remove();
 $(this).remove();
});
$('.pai').on('click', function () {
 $(this).parent('div').remove();
 $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
.pai,
.brow {
 border: 1px solid #000;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
 <div class="">p irmão 1</div>
 <div class="brow">remove irmão de cima 1</div>

 <div class="">p irmão 2</div>
 <div class="brow">remove irmão de cima 2</div>

 <div class="">Div pai 1
  <div class="pai">Filho remove pai 1</div>
 </div>

 <div class="">Div pai 2
  <div class="pai">Filho remove pai 2</div>
 </div>
 
</div>
```

*OBS: pode ser que tenha uma forma de otimizar esse código, mas eu fiz do jeito que achei mais simples de entender.*

Comment: Hugo, boa tarde. Não era bem isso que estou precisando. A cada add que eu dou, outra div é criada e seus elementos recebem um autoincremento em seus index, por exemplo "wrap-produtos-1", "wrap-produtos-2", "wrap-produtos-3" e assim por diante. Consegui fazer uma função, eu coloquei uma classe "remover" nos button "X" de cada DIV, até mesmo nas que são adicionadas. Meu problema agora está sendo o seguinte, quando excluo a última DIV, não está sendo feito o decremento do index do " Número ", ou seja, se excluo o número 4, o próximo add vem com o número 5, e não o 4 novamente. Consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta com o código e o problema atual.

Comment: @LeonardoHenriqueFaleiros sim agora ficou bem claro! Mas infelizmente para esse caso não vou ter conhecimento técnico para resolver :/. Vc teria que verificar se já exites algum item, se sim começa a contagem pelo último index + 1, ou se não tiver ninguém começa do 0. Mas infelizmente não tenho esse conhecimento. Mas vc reformulando a pergunta alguém da comunidade pode te ajudar. Outro problema vai ser "recalcular" o index de todos caso vc remova o primeiro, ou outro elemento no meio da listagem...